# virtual environments created by docker cannot be loaded inside pycharm on local machine

Tags: docker, pycharm, virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04

I have an ubuntu docker container which creates python virtual environments on a docker volume. when I try to change the project interpreter in pycharm to one of these virtual environments it gives me the following error. how can i solve this issue ?

Settings

[image: settings]

Errors

[image: error]

Error Log

[image: error logs]

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile? Mainly interested if you're using a bind mounted volume or a named volume.

Comment: @bluescores I'm using named volume, and this is how I write it in the docker run command: -v /home/<user_name>/sds_docker_volume:/home/sds_docker_volume

Comment: That looks like a bind mounted volume, where you're mounting a directory in the host filesystem into the container. That's fine in your case, because you can't access a named volume from the host file system, but you can access the contents of a bind mount.